# Does it matter what Domain Object you execute a query on in grails

Tags: grails, hql, domain-object

Does it matter what domain object you use when you execute a query? For instance, I have these two domain objects

```
Class A {
    String name
}

Class B {
    String name
}
```

If I want to get all A objects, I can do the following

```
A.executeQuery('FROM A')
```

But I can also call the same query from a different domain object and get the exact same results as so

```
B.executeQuery('FROM A')
```

Is there a difference between these two statements performance wise? Maybe something under the hood that is happening differently?

For a little more context, I am writing a service where the application will be executing queries off of domain objects dynamically. So I could either pick a base domain object and just execute off that every time, or I can maybe make an instance of the domain object with a string that is provided into the method.

Thanks

Comment: "or I can maybe make an instance of the domain object with a string that is provided into the method" - You should not create an instance of a domain object in order to execute a query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it does not matter. In this case it's just executing HQL (hibernate query) and either domain class acts exactly the same in this respect for `executeQuery`.

In your specific case I'd just use a single domain class to execute all the queries from. No need to change the type.

Comment: "In your specific case I'd just use a single domain class to execute all the queries from." - That would be a non-standard and potentially confusing thing to do.  Having just 1 domain class that you execute all of your queries on is not a recommended best practice.

Answer (score 0):

> Does it matter what domain object you use when you execute a query?

It depends on what query technique you are using.  For `executeQuery` in particular it does not.  For most other query techniques it does.  For example, `A.executeQuery('FROM A')` is the same as `B.executeQuery('FROM A')`.  `A.list()` is not the same as `B.list()`.  `A.findAllByTitle('Tribe')` is not the same as `B.findAllByTitle('Tribe')`, `A.where { ... }` is not the same as `B.where { ...}`, etc...